# python convert all keys to strings

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have nested dictionary that has some numeric keys. I need to store this dictionary as JSON and since these keys are numeric, I cant store them as JSON. I wrote the code below but it gives me the error saying the length of the dictionary has changed (`RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`).

```
def convert_to_str(dictionary):
    for key in dictionary:
        print (key)
        found = False
        non_str_keys = []
        if not isinstance(key, str):
            print(key, 'is not a string')
            dictionary[str(key)] = dictionary[key]
            non_str_keys.append(key)
        if isinstance(dictionary[str(key)], dict):
            dictionary[str(key)] = convert_to_str(dictionary[str(key)])
            non_str_keys.append(key)
        if non_str_keys:
            for each_non_str_key in non_str_keys:
                del dictionary[each_non_str_key]
    return dictionary
```

How do I avoid this? The dictionary that I have is -

```
a = {
  "age": {
    1: 25.0,
    2: 50.25,
    3: 50.0,
    4: 75.0,
    5: 14.580906789680968,
    6: [
      25.0,
      30.0,
      34.800000000000004,
      40.0,
      46.60000000000001,
      50.0,
      56.0,
      61.0,
      65.0,
      69.0,
      75.0
    ],
    "quartiles": [
      38.0,
      64.0
    ],
    "decile_event_rate": [
      0.8125,
      0.7142857142857143,
      0.65625,
      0.42857142857142855,
      0.45161290322580644,
      0.4857142857142857,
      0.5925925925925926,
      0.5,
      0.5142857142857142,
      0.375
    ]
  },
  "income": {
    "min": 10198.0,
    "mean": 55621.78666666667,
    "median": 52880.0,
    "max": 99783.0,
    "std": 24846.911384024643,
    "deciles": [
      10198.0,
      25269.4,
      31325.800000000003,
      37857.0,
      43721.8,
      52880.0,
      63996.0,
      72526.9,
      82388.2,
      89765.90000000001,
      99783.0
    ],
    "quartiles": [
      35088.5,
      78687.25
    ],
    "decile_event_rate": [
      0.6666666666666666,
      0.6,
      0.5333333333333333,
      0.5666666666666667,
      0.5,
      0.6451612903225806,
      0.4827586206896552,
      0.5,
      0.5666666666666667,
      0.5
    ]
  },
  "edu_yrs": {
    "min": 0.0,
    "mean": 12.73,
    "median": 13.0,
    "max": 25.0,
    "std": 7.86234623342895,
    "deciles": [
      0.0,
      2.0,
      4.0,
      7.0,
      9.600000000000009,
      13.0,
      16.0,
      18.0,
      21.200000000000017,
      23.0,
      25.0
    ],
    "quartiles": [
      6.0,
      20.0
    ],
    "decile_event_rate": [
      0.5384615384615384,
      0.6521739130434783,
      0.5151515151515151,
      0.48,
      0.6111111111111112,
      0.5,
      0.5,
      0.6071428571428571,
      0.5151515151515151,
      0.6666666666666666
    ]
  },
  "yrs_since_exercise": {
    "min": 0.0,
    "mean": 18.566666666666666,
    "median": 16.0,
    "max": 60.0,
    "std": 14.417527732194037,
    "deciles": [
      0.0,
      3.0,
      5.0,
      8.0,
      12.0,
      16.0,
      20.0,
      25.0,
      31.0,
      41.0,
      60.0
    ],
    "quartiles": [
      6.0,
      27.0
    ],
    "decile_event_rate": [
      1.0,
      1.0,
      1.0,
      0.9629629629629629,
      0.75,
      0.4857142857142857,
      0.15384615384615385,
      0.06666666666666667,
      0.0,
      0.0
    ]
  },
  "security_label": {
    "event_rate": {
      "A": {
        "1.0": 0.6,
        "0.0": 0.4
      },
      "B": {
        "1.0": 0.57,
        "0.0": 0.43
      },
      "C": {
        "0.0": 0.5,
        "1.0": 0.5
      }
    },
    "freq": {
      "A": 100,
      "B": 100,
      "C": 100
    },
    "var_type": "categorical"
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
    json.dump(self.entity_data, open(path, 'w'), indent=2, cls=CustomEncoder)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 430, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 404, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 404, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 404, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 376, in _iterencode_dict
    raise TypeError("key " + repr(key) + " is not a string")
TypeError: key 0 is not a string
```

Adding an image of the error[image]

**EDIT-2**

I got serialization errors ebfore for using numpy objects. So I began,using this encoder to convert them to python objects.

```
class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.integer):
            return int(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, np.floating):
            return float(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        else:
            return super(CustomEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

I have been doing the `json.dump` while using `cls = CustomEncoder`. This is the command I had used

```
 json.dump(self.entity_data, open(path, 'w'), indent=2, cls=CustomEncoder)
```

Comment: The main reason you are getting that error is that you are replacing your dicitonary in place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to recursively convert all keys; generate a *new* dictionary with a dict comprehension, that's much easier than altering the keys in-place. You can't add string keys and delete the non-string keys in a dictionary you are iterating over, because that mutates the hash table, which can easily alter the order the dictionary keys are listed in, so this is not permitted.

You should not forget to handle lists; they too can contain further dictionaries.

Whenever I need to transform a nested structure like this, I'd use the [`@functools.singledispatch` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) to split out handling for the different container types to different functions:

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def keys_to_strings(ob):
    return ob

@keys_to_strings.register
def _handle_dict(ob: dict):
    return {str(k): keys_to_strings(v) for k, v in ob.items()}

@keys_to_strings.register
def _handle_list(ob: list):
    return [keys_to_strings(v) for v in ob]
```

Then JSON encode the result of `keys_to_string()`:

```
json.dumps(keys_to_string(a))
```

*Not that this is all needed*. `json.dumps()` accepts integer keys natively, turning them to strings. Your input example *works without transforming*:

```
json.dumps(a)
```

From the [`json.dumps()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps):

> **Note:** Keys in key/value pairs of JSON are always of the type `str`. When a dictionary is converted into JSON, all the keys of the dictionary are coerced to strings. As a result of this, if a dictionary is converted into JSON and then back into a dictionary, the dictionary may not equal the original one. That is, `loads(dumps(x)) != x` if `x` has non-string keys.

This only applies to types that *JSON could otherwise already handle*, so `None`, booleans, `float` and `int` objects. For anything else, you'd still get your exception. You probably have an object whose *representation* is `0`, but it is not a Python `int` 0:

```
>>> json.dumps({0: 'works'})
'{"0": "works"}'
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.int32()
0
>>> json.dumps({numpy.int32(): 'fails'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
TypeError: keys must be a string
```

I picked a `numpy` integer type because that's a commonly confused integer value that is not a Python `int`.

A custom encoder, as you added to your post, won't be used for keys; that only applies to *values* in dictionaries, so if you have non-standard objects for keys, then you indeed still need to use the above recursive solution.

Comment: That's a nice usage of the `singledispatch`

Comment: I am using it with json.dump. It gave me errors like `TypeError: key 0 is not a string`

Comment: @ClockSlave: what version of Python are you using then? Or did you use a non-standard-library JSON library instead?

Comment: @ClockSlave: Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 and the forthcoming 3.7 *all* convert keys to strings. Python 2.5 did not yet include the `json` library.

Comment: I'm using the one shipped with python(`import json`).
Version: `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`

Comment: @ClockSlave: testing that now, but on 2.7 `json.dump()` uses the same serialisation as `json.dumps()` does, and integer keys are converted.

Comment: @ClockSlave: I can't reproduce this on Python 3.6 either, not with `with open('/tmp/test.json', 'w') as f: json.dump({1: 1}, f)`, or with your sample object.

Comment: @ClockSlave: what does `print(json.__file__)` show?

Comment: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py`

Comment: I have added an image to the edit section of the post.

Comment: @ClockSlave: interesting, I can't find anything that looks relevant in the Python 3.6.x changelog that would indicate that behaviour changed here.

Comment: I know it sounds stupid, but I had no problems in the json dumps till yesterday. Its just today that I have got these errors.

Comment: @ClockSlave: a traceback is still text, so a screenshot is not the best method. Digging deeper.

Comment: @ClockSlave: ah, that line is triggered if your key is not already a string, a boolean, `None`, a `float` or an `int`. In other words, *your posted example is not representative*, because *all* keys in that example are those primitive types. You only get the error if your key is of a type that *JSON doesn't support*.

Comment: Can you help me understand a little bit more? The solution that you provided works. And that is converting non-string types to string and then storing it, right? Had it been any other data type except a float, int, bool, it should have thrown an error, but it doesn't. Also i haven't changed the structure of the json. Its the same as it was. Sorry, but I am a little confused

Comment: @ClockSlave: I added a likely explanation: you have a numeric object that is not Python's `int` type, the likely candidate being a `numpy` object.

Comment: I have added another edit to the post. Could you take a look? My problem is solved for now, but I'm asking to understand a little of whats going on.

Comment: @ClockSlave: a custom encoder is only applied to values, never to dictionary keys.

Comment: Okay, alright. That probably sums it up then. Many thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3):

`json.dumps` automatically turn interger indexes to string indexes

```
>>> import json
>>> a = {'income': {'deciles': [10198.0, 25269.4, 31325.800000000003, 37857.0, 43721.8, 52880.0, 63996.0, 72526.9, 82388.2, 89765.90000000001, 99783.0], 'min': 10198.0, 'std': 24846.911384024643, 'quartiles': [35088.5, 78687.25], 'median': 52880.0, 'decile_event_rate': [0.6666666666666666, 0.6, 0.5333333333333333, 0.5666666666666667, 0.5, 0.6451612903225806, 0.4827586206896552, 0.5, 0.5666666666666667, 0.5], 'max': 99783.0, 'mean': 55621.78666666667}, 'age': {1: 25.0, 2: 50.25, 3: 50.0, 4: 75.0, 5: 14.580906789680968, 6: [25.0, 30.0, 34.800000000000004, 40.0, 46.60000000000001, 50.0, 56.0, 61.0, 65.0, 69.0, 75.0], 'quartiles': [38.0, 64.0], 'decile_event_rate': [0.8125, 0.7142857142857143, 0.65625, 0.42857142857142855, 0.45161290322580644, 0.4857142857142857, 0.5925925925925926, 0.5, 0.5142857142857142, 0.375]}, 'edu_yrs': {'deciles': [0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 7.0, 9.600000000000009, 13.0, 16.0, 18.0, 21.200000000000017, 23.0, 25.0], 'min': 0.0, 'std': 7.86234623342895, 'quartiles': [6.0, 20.0], 'median': 13.0, 'decile_event_rate': [0.5384615384615384, 0.6521739130434783, 0.5151515151515151, 0.48, 0.6111111111111112, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6071428571428571, 0.5151515151515151, 0.6666666666666666], 'max': 25.0, 'mean': 12.73}, 'security_label': {'var_type': 'categorical', 'freq': {'C': 100, 'A': 100, 'B': 100}, 'event_rate': {'C': {'0.0': 0.5, '1.0': 0.5}, 'A': {'0.0': 0.4, '1.0': 0.6}, 'B': {'0.0': 0.43, '1.0': 0.57}}}, 'yrs_since_exercise': {'deciles': [0.0, 3.0, 5.0, 8.0, 12.0, 16.0, 20.0, 25.0, 31.0, 41.0, 60.0], 'min': 0.0, 'std': 14.417527732194037, 'quartiles': [6.0, 27.0], 'median': 16.0, 'decile_event_rate': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9629629629629629, 0.75, 0.4857142857142857, 0.15384615384615385, 0.06666666666666667, 0.0, 0.0], 'max': 60.0, 'mean': 18.566666666666666}}
>>> new = json.dumps(a)  # as a json string
>>> new
'{"income": {"deciles": [10198.0, 25269.4, 31325.800000000003, 37857.0, 43721.8, 52880.0, 63996.0, 72526.9, 82388.2, 89765.90000000001, 99783.0], "min": 10198.0, "std": 24846.911384024643, "quartiles": [35088.5, 78687.25], "mean": 55621.78666666667, "decile_event_rate": [0.6666666666666666, 0.6, 0.5333333333333333, 0.5666666666666667, 0.5, 0.6451612903225806, 0.4827586206896552, 0.5, 0.5666666666666667, 0.5], "max": 99783.0, "median": 52880.0}, "age": {"1": 25.0, "2": 50.25, "3": 50.0, "4": 75.0, "5": 14.580906789680968, "6": [25.0, 30.0, 34.800000000000004, 40.0, 46.60000000000001, 50.0, 56.0, 61.0, 65.0, 69.0, 75.0], "quartiles": [38.0, 64.0], "decile_event_rate": [0.8125, 0.7142857142857143, 0.65625, 0.42857142857142855, 0.45161290322580644, 0.4857142857142857, 0.5925925925925926, 0.5, 0.5142857142857142, 0.375]}, "edu_yrs": {"deciles": [0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 7.0, 9.600000000000009, 13.0, 16.0, 18.0, 21.200000000000017, 23.0, 25.0], "min": 0.0, "std": 7.86234623342895, "quartiles": [6.0, 20.0], "mean": 12.73, "decile_event_rate": [0.5384615384615384, 0.6521739130434783, 0.5151515151515151, 0.48, 0.6111111111111112, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6071428571428571, 0.5151515151515151, 0.6666666666666666], "max": 25.0, "median": 13.0}, "security_label": {"var_type": "categorical", "freq": {"A": 100, "C": 100, "B": 100}, "event_rate": {"A": {"0.0": 0.4, "1.0": 0.6}, "C": {"0.0": 0.5, "1.0": 0.5}, "B": {"0.0": 0.43, "1.0": 0.57}}}, "yrs_since_exercise": {"deciles": [0.0, 3.0, 5.0, 8.0, 12.0, 16.0, 20.0, 25.0, 31.0, 41.0, 60.0], "min": 0.0, "std": 14.417527732194037, "quartiles": [6.0, 27.0], "mean": 18.566666666666666, "decile_event_rate": [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9629629629629629, 0.75, 0.4857142857142857, 0.15384615384615385, 0.06666666666666667, 0.0, 0.0], "max": 60.0, "median": 16.0}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this function to convert all dict keys to str keeping the values as I received them:

```
def _parse_dict_ket_to_str(d: dict):
    """To save data at mongodb need all keys as string"""
    result = {}
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                result[str(k)] = _parse_dict_ket_to_str(v)
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                result[str(k)] = [_parse_dict_ket_to_str(e) for e in v]
            else:
                result[str(k)] = v
    else:
        return d
    return result
```

If you want change other types as numpy.int64 to int, can add this to last else:

```
if isinstance(d, np.int64):
     return int(d)
```