# How to convert a python dictionary into a form where it can be accepted as **kwargs?

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword-argument

Newbie python programmer here, so i apologise if this question has been asked but i could not find an answer that i understood and could apply to my code.

basically i have a dictionary `my_dict` which is of `len(x)`, where `4 < x < 100`.

the dictionary is in the form:

```
{ 0: (bg_colour, text_colour), ..., x: (bg_colour, text_colour)) }
```

where the values of `bg_colour` and `text_colour` will be updated as the program runs.

Later in my code i want to call a function to draw rectangles on a canvas based on this dictionary, and I am meant to use the `**kwargs` as an argument to make this happen. I have tried using:
`func(**mydict)`, but get `error: keywords must be strings`.

So my question is how can I transform `my_dict` into a form where it is recognisable by `**kwargs`?
From what I have read i have to get it into a string form such as:
`my_dict = '0=(bg_colour, text_colour), ..., x=(bg_colour, text_colour)'`
and i'm thinking perhaps because the values of `my_dict` is tuples in this case, that may be the problem?
perhaps to work around this i should make two dicts; one for bg and one for text. 
but this would mean entering twice as many **kwargs into my function, and i would prefer not to do that.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: It's because 0 is one of your keys, keys must be strings in order to map to a parameter in a function. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47568402/929999

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710391/converting-python-dict-to-kwargs

Answer (score 0):

You could build a new dictionary where you've converted the keys to strings

```
>>> def func(**mydict):
...     print(mydict)
... 
>>> my_dict = {0:(30,12),1:(99,99), 2:(16,255)}
>>> func(**{str(key):val for key,val in my_dict.items()})
{'0': (30, 12), '1': (99, 99), '2': (16, 255)}
>>>
```

But why not just define `func` to take a `dict`? If this function is taking keyword arguments, its a pretty good bet its not expecting integers as parameters, and if this kw dict isn't holding parameters, it shouldn't be a kw dict in the first place, I would think.